# Use robots.txt to crawl ONLY my sitemap

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I want to stop google from crawling my entire site - EXCEPT the sitemap, which I can use to tell google priority & last changed etc..
Is this a bad idea?
How would I do this in robots.txt?

Comment: Why would you want to stop google from doing this? And you can just open robots.txt and disallow:* and allow only your sitemap

Comment: Seems like you'd want to have 2 versions of your site map.  One would called 'robots.txt' and formatted according to robot.txt rules.  The other would be for humans.

Answer (score 0):

If you close your whole in Google Crawler then Google doesn't Crawl Sitemap.xml also.

Thanks